# AWS cognito custom user roles for authorization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

AWS cognito's documentation suggest all the roles around IAM. How to make meaningful role that my application (resource-server) understands?

Answer (score 6):

I have used AWS Cognito extensively in my applications and I can try helping you here.

Whatever you are saying is possible using Cognito. I believe you are trying to figure one pattern to map your application roles to Cognito/AWS IAM roles.

All Cognito users in the pool can be segregated under different Cognito Groups. documentation is here -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-user-groups.html

Each Cognito user group has to be mapped with corresponding IAM Role (permissions you can customize).

Now, these groups need to have one to one mapping with the user role/group in the application.

These groups can be leveraged in 2 different ways. We are considering the design pattern with UI layer (eg:AngularJS) -> AWS APi Gateway -> RestAPI (Lambda/hosted as an application in Beanstalk/container/Ec2/etc.)

1. The UI controls need to be displayed according to the user group. For example, a super admin will see all the links and menus, full privilege. But for normal end-user, limited links and menus will be visible. In order to achieve this, you can use some of the plugins for AngularJS (may be different in your case) to control the rendering of UI based on group information.
2. The API layer can be protected by introducing an authorization layer by setting the Authorizer configuration of API Gateway as IAM/Cognito. So before a request hits the API hosted in back-end, API gateway will check whether the requested user group has permission to access the API.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think you understood the problem correctly - I understand each cognito user is implicitly assigned to a user-group. I am trying to figure out a way so application can tell the cognito to assign a role. For example - when teacher signups vs when student signups - I want to allocate them to different role (or user group). One way of doing this is via two different user-pool - I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: Cognito User Group can be defined and we can create a role and attach to each group. There is no need to create two different user pools. Before, user registration happens, you can create the Cognito User Group and keep it ready. based on the information (Teacher/Student) add them to the group.

Comment: Api Reference to add user to Cognito group from code -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminAddUserToGroup.html

Comment: Thanks @Robin - do you know how can this be configured when we use the hosted UI ?

Comment: AWS has introduced a development layer on top of Cognito using AWS Amplify, please explore this before you start. https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/js

Comment: This slide summaries AWS Cognito  https://www.slideshare.net/awsugkochi/acdkochi19-enterprise-grade-security-for-web-and-mobile-applications-on-aws

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean too much, but roles are for accessing AWS resources. Cognito can be used with an Identity Pool to grant temporary credentials to AWS resources. This means you can put your server/ec2 instance behind an API gateway configured with IAM authentication, and create an authenticated role in your Identity Pool which allows HTTP calls to your API GW.

Comment: Thank you - In my app I am trying to offload authentication/registration to cognito and once the user is authenticated they don't do anything related to AWS services, they have to work with my resource-server (applicaiton) and do authorized operation based on the role granted.